# What's the difference between using int 0x20 and int 0x21 / ah=0x4C to exit a 16-bit assembly program?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

At various times, I've used both

```
int 0x20
```

and

```
mov ah, 0x4c
int 0x21
```

as ways of ending a 16-bit assembly program.

But what is the difference between the two?

---

**EDIT**: Thanks for your comments everyone.  Following up on Alexey's reference to the PSP (program segment prefix), yielded [this nugget from Microsoft MASM support](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/072/Q72848/).

The article seems to suggest there's more to the difference than just return codes.

Happy to award the accepted answer to anyone who can tie the two together a bit more definitively.

Comment: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/difference-between-int-0x20-and-int-0x21-0x4c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, some background. DOS uses interrupt 21h for its system calls. AH is used to demultiplex the various functions INT 21h provides. When a program is executed, DOS puts before it 256 bytes known as the PSP (Program Segment Prefix), which contain information about the process.

The original exit function in DOS is `INT 21/AH=00`. Now, apparently DOS developers decided that returning from a program should be a way to exit the program (did this come from CP/M?). `RET` (near) pops a word from the stack and jumps to it. So, when a program is created, its stack starts with a word `0000`. This is the start of the PSP. So, at the start of the PSP there is code to terminate the program. To keep that code small, `INT 20h` acts as an alias to `MOV AH,00h ; INT 21h`.

[Edit: This can be seen in the screenshot below.]

DOS 2.0 took many things from Unix, including return codes. So, a new INT 21h function appeared, `INT 21h/AH=4ch`, which takes a return code to return it to the OS. This function is also designed to work with EXE files (AFAIR also new in DOS 2.0), which can have several segments. The previous exit functions (INT 20h and INT 21h/00) assume CS is the same as it was at program startup on a COM program, that is, it points to the PSP 256 bytes before the program.

[Edit: [image: Illustration of DOS program structure, using <code>debug</code>]

Historical note: on CP/M, there were 3 ways to exit a program:

- Calling BDOS function 0 (the equivalent of INT 21 AH=00h, DOS function 0)
- Jumping to the WBOOTF location at 0000h (the equivalent of PSP offset 000h)
- RETurning

The WBOOTF location consisted of 3 bytes: 1 byte for a jump, 2 bytes for the jump target (the WBOOT function in BDOS).

In early versions of CP/M, calling BDOS function 0 or jumping to WBOOT caused parts of CP/M to be reloaded from disk (warm boot), and some OS initialization to be subsequently run; while RETurning directly returned to the CCP (Console Command Processor, the equivalent of COMMAND.COM), which then prompted for the next command line. AFAIU, CP/M 3 was usually loaded in ROM, and returning returned to the WBOOT location, causing a reload of parts of the OS from ROM.

Comment: With your permission, I'd like to insert an annotated screenshot that verifies what you described.  I'll edit your response, and paste it in -- see what you think.  (Won't be offended if you'd rather not!)  Let me know.

Answer (score 7):

The later, int 0x21, allows you to specify a return code.

The return code is placed in the register AL.

http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah4c

Comment: Is this the only difference?  I've noticed that in some environments (e.g. DOSbox, int 0x20 works fine, while int 0x21 goes haywire.)

Comment: Define "haywire".  If for example you have an indeterminate value in AL and a subsequent step checks the return code, chances are pretty good that you returned a non-zero return code.  That is usually interpreted as some sort of program failure by convention.

Comment: @AKE In a .COM program you can execute `RET` for exiting as well (provided you don't have any stuff of yours still unpopped from the stack and you haven't corrupted any of structures). That `RET` transfers control to `int 0x20`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: `RET` -- didn't know that.  By corrupted structures, do you mean registers `bx`, `ds`, `bp`, and `ss`?  Or something else?

Comment: @AKE No, parts of the `PSP` and the original stack contents at program startup.

Comment: @EricJ.: "haywire", meaning a pile of non-printing ASCII characters in the console, something like you might see if you tried to print a string with no null terminator.  Doubt it was an indeterminate value in AL, since the test program was very simple: `ORG 0x100` `nop` `int 0x20` on the one hand and `ORG 0x100` `mov ah, 0x09` `int 0x21` on the other.  (I should add, the tests were assembled in NASM with `-f` switch to produce 16-bit COM file which were then run in DOSbox.)

Comment: @AKE: Did you just write `mov ah, 0x09` ? Maybe you meant `mov ah, 0x4c`, or, better yet, `mov ax,0x4c00`.

Comment: Note that the difference comes from DOS originally not using return codes, then taking the idea of return codes from Unix for DOS 2.0.

Comment: @ninjalj: Oops!  You're right, I meant `mov ah, 0x4c`.  (Had strings on the brain.)

Comment: @EricJ.: Sorry for the confusion.  ninjalj spotted a typo in my test code -- I was sending ID `09h` for Display String routine and NOT the exit routine...  That explains the pile of non-printing ASCII chars... it was exactly printing with no null termination - doh!  (+1) for moving the conversation forward.

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for the great spot, I've edited the question to try to get to the bottom of the difference now that it's not due entirely to user error...

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I followed up on your mention of the PSP, and it seems that this is at the heart of the difference.  I've edited the question to reflect this -- would appreciate if you can shed a bit more light on this.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Sorry but I'm not sure I'm following the significance.

Comment: @AKE Both say that upon entry to int 0x20, the caller's CS must point to the program's PSP. That's all there is. And this is always the case for .COM programs (unless, of course, you modify CS), but it's different with .EXEs and that article describes how to workaround it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I know.

```
MOV AH, 0x4C
INT 0x21
```

Ends the running EXE file, the EXE file must be ended this way, because codesegment register CS. Correct me if I'm wrong but if you end COM files this way you get unexpected results (crashes, hangs, reboots etc). Therefore

```
INT 0x20
```

Ends a COM file.

CS is the same as it was at program startup on a COM program, that is, it points to the PSP 256 bytes before the program. (CodeSegment InstructionPointer CS:IP, CS contains codesegment). Yes we are talking registers, variables they are like a cupboard, I works like you can put something correctly in a drawer. AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=0000 (CX is composed of CL and CH) etc.

I thought COM files were generally limited to 64K ALWAYS. The second reason I thought was that COM files don't have a DATA SEGMENT, they do have data but it resides in the same segment as the code. I thought they didn't have ANY segment except for the CODE, All data in a COM file is stored within 64K. EXE files do have a segment, some EXE files can have more segments (CS:IP) when using the correct memory model (see Intel Memory Model).

- Tiny*   `CS=DS=SS`
- Small   `DS=SS`
- Medium  `DS=SS`, multiple code segments
- Compact single code segment, multiple data segments
- Large   multiple code and data segments
- Huge    multiple code and data segments; single array may be >64 KB

EXE files have a limit of 64K using memory model SMALL. 
When using larger memory models and far 32 bit pointers, you can address more than 64K (still limited). I thought that was the 'trick'.

Now everyone is complaining on me why should you use EXE files. Above are the reasons. Memory model comes from wikipedia. For those who don't care, I learned this the hard way from professionals. Peter Norton and John Socha. From Norton Utilities (the person behind The Norton Commander for DOS). He had a book about assembly something like "Assembly for the IBM-PC". You should read it, he explains it best. He was like a good teacher for me. Microsoft CodeView clarified me a lot. Programming in DOS C? Turbo C 2.0 is the best you can get. Oh, and I don't program anymore.

Comment: If you cut out some of the attitude this could be a very helpful answer.

Comment: `AH=0x4c` / `INT 0x21` will safely exit a .com file, too; see the other answers.  And if you want to set your program's exit status, you *have* to use that instead of `int 0x20`.